# In React project, "this" converts into "undefined"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

A very simple code

```
var App = React.createClass({
    handleForm: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    render: () => {
        return (
            <form>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleForm}>Go</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Gets converted into

```
// ...
_react2['default'].createElement(
    'button',
    { type: 'submit', onClick: undefined.handleFormSubmit },
    'Go'
)
```

But why? And do I need to bind all the things explicitly (including `this.setState` which I can't get working for the same reason)?

I'm using react 0.13.3 with webpack 1.12.2 and babel-loader 5.3.2. Haven't faced such a problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an arrow function as the value of a property in an object literal, the binding to `this` is that of the function's declaration scope just like any arrow function. In ES6 module code the value of `this` in the outermost context is defined to be `undefined` so Babel is simply inlining this value. What you want to do is this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <form>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleForm}>Go</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
});
```

As a final note, you do not need to bind any member functions when using `React.createClass` as React will do this for you automatically and in a more efficient way than with `Function.prototype.bind`.

*Thank you @loganfsmyth for the update about why `this` is `undefined`.*

Comment: It's not actually strict mode that causes `undefined` in this case. Babel parses everything as an ES6 module, and `this` in an ES6 module is explicitly `undefined` in the spec.

Comment: @loganfsmyth is it not the case that `this` is defined as `undefined` in module code because the spec defines it to be in strict mode? https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-strict-mode-code

Comment: @lukewestby you can reference the final spec now :)

Comment: Apologies! http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code Thanks @JMM

Comment: No problem. For some reason I still see people link to the draft quite a bit. Just habit I guess.

Comment: Strict mode defines `this` behavior for function calls, among other things, including that calling a function with `undefined`/`null` doesn't convert to global, but a module isn't a function. [8.1.1.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records-getthisbinding) defines that `this` in the global environment is the actual global object, and [8.1.1.5.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-environment-records-getthisbinding) explicitly says that `this` in a module environment is `undefined`.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the detailed references, I'll update my answer to be more accurate.